# React Redux Router keeps throwing errors. _reactInternalInstance$7bszmuqv99s' of null

Tags: reactjs, redux, router

I am rewriting a website using React and redux.

index.js

```js
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(...middleware)
);

store.dispatch(getAllMenu());

render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Menu />
     </BrowserRouter>),

  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Routes.js

```js
*jshint esversion: 6 */
import React from 'react';  
import { Router, Route} from 'react-router';  
import Menu from './containers/Menu';  
import subMenu from './containers/subMenu/subMenu'; 


const Routes = (props) => (
    <Router {...props}>
        <Route path="/" component={Menu}>
            <Route path="/subMenu" component={subMenu} />
        </Route>
    </Router> 
);

export default Routes;
```

Menu.js(App.js)

```js
import React from 'react'
import HeaderContainer from './HeaderContainer'
import ProductsContainer from './MenuContainer'
import Header from '../components/Header/Header'

const Menu = () => (
  <div>
    <HeaderContainer />
    <Header />
    <section className="content menuCategoryPage">
      <h1 className="pageTitle">Bob Evans Menu</h1>
      <hr/>
      <ProductsContainer />
    </section>
  </div>
)

export default Menu
```

Header.js

```js
const Header = () => (
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to='/'>Menu</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/subMenu'>Roster</Link></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
)

export default Header;
```

What am I doing wrong? I keep getting this error:

> ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$1awl81loycp' of null

Comment: where does it point at?

Comment: It points at ReactDOMComponentTRee.js "function getClosestInstanceFromNode(node) {
  if (node[internalInstanceKey]) {
    return node[internalInstanceKey];
  }"

Comment: the issue was minor. I kept doing import { Link} from 'react-router'; instead of import { Link} from 'react-router-dom'; and that fixed it